# Existence of a holomorphic function in the open disc $D=\{z\in \mathbb{C}: |z|<1\}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, functions

Let $D=\{z\in \mathbb{C}: |z|<1\}$. Then there exists a holomorphic function $$f:D\to \bar{D}$$ with $f(0)=0$ with the property

1. $f'(0)=1/2$
2. $|f(1/3)|=1/4$
3. $f(1/3)=1/2$
4. $|f'(0)|=\sec{\pi/6}$

I have no idea how to come up with such a fuction, which satisfies atmost **two** of the above conditions as there are contradictory statements.  I tried to guess some but it does not work. Is there any general rule to solve this kind of problems? Which options are true? Please help me out. Any hint is sufficient.

**edit** - Answer says $1$ and $2$ are correct.

Comment: Please look carefully at what you wrote. There are several contradictions.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Ya there are contradictory statements but i want a function which satisfies either 1 and 2 or 3 and 4

Comment: Would be good to state it in your original post

Comment: Yes I have edited it now

Comment: I assume this is supposed to be **four** questions, one for each condition?

Comment: @mrf any hints??

Comment: Assuming it's four separate questions, Schwarz' lemma is the key.

Comment: Got it thanks @mrf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By [Schwarz lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma), $1$, $2$ and $3$ are true trivially.

Comment: im not getting  how option 3  is true ?? can u elaboarte more

Answer (score 0):

1. True. Choose $f(z)=\frac{z}{2}.$
2. True. Choose $f(z)=\frac{3z}{4}.$
3. False. By Schwarz Lemma $|f(z)|\leq|z|$.
4. False. By Schwarz Lemma $|f'(0)|\leq 1$.

Answer (score -1):

I think 3rd is not true. As by Schwarz lemma $|f(z)|\leq|z|$ which is not true in 3rd option

Comment: In posting an Answer to this six month old Question, you should consider the Comments and previous Answers in an effort to understand the problem being addressed.  The original poster did not do a perfect job in stating what was to be shown initially, and also didn't edit perfectly to clarify the problem, but taking everything together my guess is that your brief response does not fully address the problem nor improve upon the Accepted Answer.  There are many ways to supplement existing answers with useful information, so perhaps it is worth trying again while this is fresh in your mind.