# Is there exists a holomorphic function $f:D\to \bar{D}$ with $f(0)=0$ with the property $f(1/3)=1/2$???

Tags: complex-analysis

I got  the  question From here [Existence of a holomorphic function in the open disc $D=\{z\in \mathbb{C}: |z|<1\}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1502877/existence-of-a-holomorphic-function-in-the-open-disc-d-z-in-mathbbc-z1)..

Let $D=\{z\in \mathbb{C}: |z|<1\}$. Then there exists a holomorphic function $$f:D\to \bar{D}$$ with $f(0)=0$ with the property

1. $f'(0)=1/2$
2. $|f(1/3)|=1/4$
3. $f(1/3)=1/2$
4. $|f'(0)|=\sec{\pi/6}$

My attempts :   i got option 1) and 2) correct  and option 3  and option 4  is false   By schawrz lemma   ..but  here  [Existence of a holomorphic function in the open disc $D=\{z\in \mathbb{C}: |z|<1\}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1502877/existence-of-a-holomorphic-function-in-the-open-disc-d-z-in-mathbbc-z1).....
it  written that  option 3  is also  true  ,,,,im getting  confused
Is there exists a holomorphic function $f:D\to \bar{D}$ with $f(0)=0$ with the property $f(1/3)=1/2$???

Comment: Conditions 2. and 3. exclude each other, so do 1. and 4.

Comment: yes option 4  is also not correct ?  my question is that   why option 3 is correct ??

Comment: I think you should make it clear that you're looking for a separate function for each condition, not one function for all four conditions (as I initially thought).

Comment: actually  im not able  to catch that  function  which satisfies option 3

Comment: @T.Bongers Missed that, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A holomorphic function $f : D \to \overline{D}$ such that $f(0) = 0$ and $f \left( \frac{1}{3} \right) = \frac{1}{2}$ cannot exist from the Schwarz lemma, since it must satisfy

$$\left| f \left( \frac{1}{3} \right) \right| \leqslant \frac{1}{3}.$$

Comment: It's worth mentioning that Schwarz lemma also implies $|f'(0)| \le 1$, which precludes option (4).

Comment: But accordingt previous  post  : 1, 2 and 3 are true trivially....im not getting  How  option 3 is true  Trivailly

Comment: thanks   that mean  option 3  is not correct